# How to solve this related rates calculus problem?

Tags: calculus

An oil rig lies 20 km off the coast of Newfoundland. A town lies 80 km along the coast from the nearest point on land to the rig. A pipe is to be drilled from the rig to the town. The cost per km of the pipe under water is \$2.5 million, but on land is \$1.5 million. 
Find the route that results in the cheapest pipeline, and determine that lowest cost.

I was struggling to do this problem and I have no idea how to start. Please help!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Draw a few maps of how the rig could be connected to the town with a variety of points where the pipe meets the land.  Label the length of the section on land and at sea with a variable e.g. $l$ and $s$ and then try to come up with a formula for the cost.

Comment: I agree with @badjohn. Start by drawing a map and writing the distances on the map. Come back when you have the map and tell us what you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the pipe length of on land. Then, the length under the water has to be according to the diagram,

$$\sqrt{20^2+(80-x)^2}$$

So, the total construction cost as $x$ varies takes the form

$$c(x)=2.5\sqrt{20^2+(80-x)^2}+1.5x.$$

Then, the optimal pipe length for the cheapest cost can be found by setting $dc(x)/dx=0$. You should find 65 miles of pipes on land.

[image]

Comment: Nice job. Note to OP: Draw a picture!